# How to disable AllowInvalid in app script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following snippet:

```
let validationRule   = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(DropDownList).build();
  sheet.getRange(3,3,1,1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
```

I want to set [getAllowInvalid()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation#getAllowInvalid()) to false so that if someone enters the invalid data it must be rejected by the cell. where do I add this `getAllowInvalid(False)` to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get` as the name suggests, only retrieves the `allowInvalid` configuration. To `set`, you need to [`setAllowInvalid()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#setallowinvalidallowinvaliddata) on `DataValidationBuilder`:

```
SpreadsheetApp //class: SpreadsheetApp
 .newDataValidation()//class: DataValidationBuilder 
 .requireValueInList(DropDownList)//class: DataValidationBuilder
 .setAllowInvalid(false)//class: DataValidationBuilder
 .build();//class: DataValidation
```